# Modal Confirmation trying call another Modal Confirmation

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog, simplemodal

I have a problem I been trying to solve but as to no avail, can anyone help me please

Here is the result i want

1. I have a modal dialog already popup
2. it has 2 button Ok and Cancel
3. When i press Ok button, it should trigger another modal dialog.

Is that possible because when i click Ok button the timing is that it finish the process first since the second calling is part of the first dialog box it does not open the second modal.

Answer (score 0):

You may should try this [jqModal](http://dev.iceburg.net/jquery/jqModal/#examples). It can be implemented to create nested modal dialog.

There is a simple way to create nested dialog. You can use [jQuery EasyUI messager](http://www.jeasyui.com/documentation/messager.php). For example:

```
$.messager.confirm('Confirm','Are you sure you want to go to step 2?',function(r){  
  if (r){  
     // use nested dialog
     $.messager.confirm('Confirm','Are you sure you want to go to step 3?',function(r){  
         if (r){  
            $.messager.alert('Info','This is step 3!');  
         } else {  
            $.messager.alert('Warning','You finished step 2!');
         }
     });  
  } else {  
     $.messager.alert('Warning','You finished step 1!');
  }  
});
```

Hope it could be your alternative way :-)

Answer (score 0):

What is the first process you do in first dialog? I implemented several nested dialog as well. I am using $.ajax to do the processing of the first dialog, and then open the second dialog using the success method:

```
    $firstdialog.dialog("option", "buttons", {
            "Submit": function () {
                    $.ajax({
                           url: '...',
                           type: 'POST',
                           data: { ... },
                           success: function (result) { $seconddialog.dialog('open'); }
                     });    
            },
            "Cancel": function () {
                $firstdialog.dialog('close');

            }
        });
```

Hope this helped :)